# How to remove the space and display only text (like awk)?

Tags: powershell, awk

There is a Linux script which is taking docker volume and displaying volumes matches string.

```
docker volume ls | grep -i $volname | awk '{print $2}'
```

I need to convert this script to work in windows environment. So PowerShell is my choice. `Select-String` works more or less like `grep`.

```
docker volume ls | Select-String $volname
```

but there is no equivalent to `awk` in PowerShell. So I tried to split using whitespace:

```
 $volList = docker volume ls |
            Select-String "winvolume" |
            foreach { $_ -split " " }
```

but it has many empty elements (13 empty elements) in the array. I need to remove all the empty elements and have only elements with text. How to achieve this in PowerShell?

Comment: on the split subject - the `.Split()` string method has split options. one of them is `RemoveEmptyEntries`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select-String` produces `MatchInfo` objects, from which you need to expand the relevant information first. Use PowerShell operators instead.

```
((docker volume ls) -match $volname -split ' +')[1]
```

Splitting at the expression `' +'` treats consecutive spaces as a single delimiter, like `awk` does.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the `-split` operator in a slightly different way.  For example, for this string:

`"this    string  has lots of  spaces      in it   "`

You can get only the 'words' by doing this:

`-split "this    string  has lots of  spaces      in it   "`

Which gives:

```
this
string
has
lots
of
spaces
in
it
```

So in your case, your code would be:

```
 $volList = docker volume ls |
            Select-String "winvolume" |
            foreach { -split $_ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `ConvertFrom-String`.

```
docker volume ls | Select-String winvolume | ConvertFrom-String | ForEach-Object P2
```

It has an alias:

```
docker volume ls | sls winvolume | cfs | % P2
```

Please be aware that if the text contains decimals, they will be rounded. So it is better not to use in scripts